# Simulink and STATCOM

Tags: simulink

I am studying a Simulink model of a 100 kW grid-connected solar PV array (http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/examples/detailed-model-of-a-100-kw-grid-connected-pv-array.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).

I have implemented a voltage sag with a three phase fault between a step-down transformer and the grid. I am now trying to include a STATCOM (http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/examples/d-statcom-average-model.html) to alleviate the voltage sag. However, I'm not sure where to place the STATCOM. I've tried it inside the utility, between the utility and the transformer, and between the RL and the transformer.

Any other ideas of where I should place it or what settings I should change inside the STATCOM?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just asking for general advice doesn't fit the stackexchange Q&A format. I suggest you read the first couple of topics under "Asking" [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and recompose your question.

Comment: Updated it, thanks.